# Routing a LAN through OpenVPN on OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: routing, openbsd, openvpn, pf

I'm configuring an OpenVPN gateway to allow a LAN access to the internet through the tunnel. The gateway is running OpenBSD 5.5-stable amd64 on the PC Engines APU platform.

The LAN contains `re1`, `re2`, and `ral0` interfaces. It also contains `vether0` which hosts the local `192.168.2.0/24` network. These interfaces are linked under `bridge0` to provide a common gateway, subnet, and DHCP via `dhcpd`.

The VPN is established and `tun0` is opened. The gateway itself can access the VPN just fine.

The problem is that, by default, the hosts access the VPN with their native `192.168.2.0/24` addresses. NAT is needed to translate the local network to the VPN network at `10.0.1.0/24`.

I have tried the following `pf.conf` configurations:

```
# pf.conf -- 10.0.1.10 is my tun0 gateway
set skip on lo
block return
pass in quick on { vether0 re1 re2 ral0 } from 192.168.2.0/24 to !10.0.0.0/8 nat-to 10.0.1.10
pass
```

I had similar results with these rules:

```
# pf.conf
...
pass in from any nat-to 10.0.1.10
pass out from tun0 to any
```

This allows LAN traffic to pass through `tun0` with a source address of `10.0.1.10`, and return traffic is passed back to the respective host. The new problem is that return traffic still does not appear to be routing correctly.

For example, I can ping `8.8.8.8` and `google.com` from any LAN host, however the first reply is ALWAYS dropped between `tun0` and the return interface. Tools like `dig`, `nslookup`, `traceroute`, and `ping` are generally sluggish and take far longer than they should. Despite some traffic still passing, browsers and other applications are unusable.

`tcpdump` demonstrating the loss:

```
# 192.168.2.103 is a LAN host
# 74.125.131.139 is google.com

# on ral0
20:59:35.668251 192.168.2.103 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request <-- no reply
20:59:40.651184 192.168.2.103 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:40.736748 74.125.131.139 > 192.168.2.103: icmp: echo reply
20:59:41.656101 192.168.2.103 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:41.741251 74.125.131.139 > 192.168.2.103: icmp: echo reply
20:59:42.661071 192.168.2.103 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:42.802410 74.125.131.139 > 192.168.2.103: icmp: echo reply

# on tun0
20:59:35.668359 10.0.1.10 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:35.764052 74.125.131.139 > 10.0.1.10: icmp: echo reply <-- here's the missing reply, it didn't get to ral0
20:59:40.651221 10.0.1.10 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:40.736721 74.125.131.139 > 10.0.1.10: icmp: echo reply <-- but the of the replies rest did
20:59:41.656138 10.0.1.10 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:41.741226 74.125.131.139 > 10.0.1.10: icmp: echo reply
20:59:42.661107 10.0.1.10 > 74.125.131.139: icmp: echo request
20:59:42.802372 74.125.131.139 > 10.0.1.10: icmp: echo reply
```

I know that this is almost certainly a NAT issue in `pf.conf` but after so many configuration attempts I'm having trouble finding the correct way to go about passing traffic.

When I was using DD-WRT and `iptables`, this was my configuration:

```
iptables -D FORWARD -i tun1 -j logaccept
iptables -D FORWARD -o tun1 -j logaccept
```

I'm not sure how to "port" this to `pf`, though. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a `pf.conf` issue. Some extra time spent studying the [OpenBSD PF NAT](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/nat.html) page lead me to the following rule which allowed traffic to pass correctly through the `tun0` interface:

```
# /etc/pf.conf
pass out on tun0 inet from 192.168.2.0/24 to any flags S/SA nat-to (tun0) round-robin
```

This essentially reads: pass traffic from the local network destined for any address out on `tun0`, IPv4 specifically, only look at the `syn` and `ack` flags, and perform outbound NAT  using `tun0`. The parentheses around `(tun0)` tell `pf` to automatically update the rule when the interface changes its address. This may occur if your VPN supports multiple peers and you failover, and thus manually reloading the ruleset becomes unnecessary.

Some time on the [OpenBSD PF Filtering](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html) page helped me refine the rule:

```
# /etc/pf.conf
pass out on $vpn_if inet proto { $protos } from $lan_net to any flags S/SA modulate state nat-to ($vpn_if) round-robin
pass in  on $vpn_if inet proto { $protos } from $vpn_gw  to any flags S/SA modulate state
```

The `modulate state` flag allows `pf` to substitute a stronger Initial Sequence Number which may help protect some operating systems on the network.

The gateway is working great now and I'm onto more complex `pf.conf` configurations.